# What's the best approach to storing JWTs on the client

Tags: authentication, jwt

I'm developing a web application and I want to use token based authentication, but after implementing the feature on the server side I got stuck on trying to figure out what is the best approach to storing JWTs on the client.

I found myself in a series of tradeoffs between security and "ease of development".

### httpOnly cookie

As we know httpOnly cookies are the best way to store tokens safely and protect them from XSS attacks, but then how would the client access the value of it if the JWT is stored in a cookie? JavaScript won't be allowed to read httpOnly cookies. How would the client handle routes authentication? The browser won't automatically set the `Authorization` header like it does with cookies.

### Local storage

As we know local storage is safe in terms of CSRF attacks but not in terms of XSS attacks. It is common knowledge trying to stay away from storing sensitive data in local storage.

### The solution

I have elaborated the following solution:

I could store the JWT in a httpOnly cookie. The server wouldn't accept requests without the `Authorization` header so the solution would be having a middleware on the server placed before the authentication one that would read the token from the cookie, set the `Authorization` header and finally pass the request to the next handler.

Pros:

- It is a safe way to store the JWT.
- This would solve the problem of routes authentication so that when the user visits `https://example.com/protected` their request would be authorized getting around the browser not setting the `Authorization` header automatically (the server would do it).

Cons:

- Wouldn't this kinda defeat the purpose of token based authentication?

I would appreciate if you guys could point me in the right direction and give suggestions, tell me if I am overcomplicating things and if there is a better way.

Comment: This is somewhat opinionated. My advice is that local storage is fine. HttpOnly cookies are only a partial mitigation against XSS. Most XSS flaws can still be maliciously exploited even with it in place. Some security firms do advise against local storage though.

Comment: Why do you need it in the Authorization header? Your middleware could auth using the cookie value.